# Get relation of a collection in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So simple but can't find how to do it in rails. I have a specific active record collection of users. Something like `users = User.where(blabla)`. Given this collection is there a simple way to get all posts that those users have? Similar to User.posts, only for all users in that collection.

Post belongs_to User, User has_many posts.

Thanks!

Comment: Simple, `Post.all`

Comment: Sorry, meant to say all posts by all users _from that collection_

Comment: From what collection, `posts`? For which you have a model `Post`?

Comment: I have a collection of users. `users = User.where(blabla)`. Wondering if there is a simple way to get a collection of all posts that those users have. So something like `User.posts` only for all users in that collection.

Comment: In this case, should be as simple as `Post.where(user_id: users.ids)` or something like that.

Comment: Ah, nice one.That works, (I also found that you can simply do `Post.where(user: users)` ) but both of these still do two queries (fetching users and posts separately). I would love to get it down to one, like with a `joins` method.  With joins I know I could do `Post.joins(:users).where('query for users')` . That would translate to a single query. But I already have this constructed collection, and trying to just do smth like `Post.joins users`. I'll leave this question for a bit, and if nothing better comes up will accept this as an anwer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your Post model has a user_id with an association called "user", you can do something like this:

```
Post.where(user_id: User.where(blablah))
```

or

```
Post.joins(:user).where(users: {<user conditions>})
```

You'll need to be able to use the Hash form for the user conditions to use the second option. For example:

```
Post.joins(:user).where(users: {role: 'member'})
```

If your users query is more complex, you can create a scope for it:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  scope :special, -> { where(< user conditions go here>) }
end
```

And then merge it with the Post query:

```
Post.joins(:user).merge(User.special)
```

Comment: Hey, this is awesome! The merge bit is exactly what I was looking for. So answering my question more specifically, the answer would be `Post.joins(:user).merge(users)` where users is a collection. That results in only one db query with no subqueries which is better then `Post.where(user: users)` (creates subquery) or `Post.where(user_id: users.ids)` (creates 2 queries). 

Could you add these details to your answer? ^ I want it to be clear about the differences. Thanks.